# Printer configuration problem after OS change into Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS

Tags: printing, configuration, canon

can somebody help me please? I’m allover new on this forum and changed my laptops OS into Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS b.m.o. upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS directly while online. The problem is that I “have lost” partial contact with my Canon Pixma Model: MG2450 too called: “MG2400-series”. The machines Scanning-Function survived the changing of my OS but its Printer-Function doesn’t communicate any longer with my laptop with the new Ubuntu 22.04.1 OS.
The new Ubuntu 22.04 OS recognizes the scanning tool but not the printer ...in spite the former Ubuntu did this perfect and correctly via my laptops USB-port. Canon do not provide any support, nor has a ‘particular driver’ for Linux.

Comment: Try to add the printer in settings app and try to print a test page.

Comment: Yes for sure, I already did that before … unfortunately without result. Thanks anyway for your attention. 
Regards
Holger